# Convertir JsonArray a JAVA POJO android

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

Con retrofit consumo un JsonArray, quiero obtener elementos de la lista de Json Objetos

este es mi Json

```
{
"Codigo": 0,
"FechaHora": "2017-07-11T11:23:11",
"Mensaje": "Ok",
"Data": [
    [
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "Nombre": "Humanos",
            "Estado": 1
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "TDId": 1,
            "GOId": 1,
            "ImgId": null,
            "Nombre": "Hola",
            "Estado": 1
        }
    ]
]
}
```

quiero obtener los Elementos de Data[] este es mi metodo Retrofit

```
public void sincronizar() {

    fecha = "1990-01-01T00:00:00";
    final Object lista[] = new Object[1];
    lista[0] = fecha;
    parametroApi.setDatoG(lista);

    PedroApi service = retrofit.create(PedroApi.class);
    Call<Respuesta<JsonArray>> call = service.sincronizar(parametroApi);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Respuesta<JsonArray>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Respuesta<JsonArray>> call, Response<Respuesta<JsonArray>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                try {
                    Respuesta<JsonArray> respuesta = response.body();
                    if (respuesta.respuestaExitosa() == true) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Respuesta Exitosa" + respuesta.toString());
                        String fechas = respuesta.getFechaHora();


                        //Try
                        //Insertar en BD
                        //Actualizar Token = fecha
                        //Cath
                        //NO dio


                    } else if (respuesta.respuestaExitosa() == false) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Respuesta NO Exitosa" + respuesta.toString());

                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Ocurio una Exepcion" + e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Respuesta<JsonArray>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Falla el consumo : " + t.getMessage().toString());
            PopUp("Errorl al conectarse con el Servidor Por favor intetalo de nuevo");


        }
    });

}
```

este mi Servicio

```
 @POST("encuesta/sincronizar")
Call<Respuesta<JsonArray>> sincronizar(@Body ParametroApi<Object[]> parametroApi);
```

como puedo pasear los JsonObjects de Data[]?

Answer (score 0):

#### Problema

Recibes un **JSONArray** en vez de un **JSONObject**.

Quieres obtener el JSONArray de la propiedad clave 'data' del JSONObject, pero ahora mismo como lo describes es imposible ya que no recibes el contenido de la propiedad 'data', sino el JSONObject completo y le estás indicando a retrofit que intente convertirlo como si fuera un JSONArray.

#### Solución 1

Recibe un JSONObject en vez de un JSONArray y podrás obtener tus datos de la propiedad `data` así:

```
JSONObject json = res.body();
JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("data");
```

#### Solución 2

Recibe desde la API directamente el array de la propiedad `data` si solo necesitas esos datos.

```
JSONArray data = res.body();
```

#### Solución 3

Puedes crear un wrapper (envoltorio) o modelo que represente lo que recibes, una clase. Recibir esta como respuesta de retrofit y el los datos del array de la propiedad `data` que sea también otro wrapper.

```
class MiRespuesta {
    int Codigo;
    String FechaHora;
    String message;
    List<MiDato> misDatos;
}

class MiDato {
    int id;
    int TDId;
    int GOId;
    Integer ImgId;
    String Nombre;
    String Estado;
}

MiRespuesta mr = res.body();
List<MiDato> datos = mr.misDatos;
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, lo que hice fue obeneter un  JsonString de mi resultado en una posición de Data, ej String JsonString = getData.get(0).toString()
me cree un método que recibe como parámetro un JsonString,un Type y una Lista le verifico, lo paseo.
y ese método lo llamo en retrofit, mandando el Son String, un Type de una Clase, y por ultimo una Lista de mi clase MiDato(), así pude recorrer la lista con un for, obteniendo los valores